Divide one column to three add fill up missing numbers
That's a part of my data:
structure(list(Testa = c(-1L, -1L, -1L, 
                                              -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L), Pre = c(NaN, NaN, NaN, 
                                                                                                NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN), Fract = c(NaN, NaN, 
                                                                                                                                                      NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN), Terms = c(-1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                               -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L), Time = c(NaN, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN), Matches = c("y15", "b6", "b7", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "b11", "y9", "b8(2+)", "y10(3+)", "b12(5+)")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Let's focus on column Matches. I would like to divide it to three columns Matches2, etc.. and fill up with the scheme like below - desired output:
Take a first character (letter: y or b) to first column, in second column should be a next character - number after the letter and in last column should be a number from bracket () without + and the one which do not have a bracket at all should be filled with number 1.

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df |>
  separate_wider_regex(Matches, 
                       c(Matches1 = "^.", Matches2 = ".*", "\\(", Matches3 = "\\d+"), 
                       too_few = "align_start", cols_remove = FALSE) |>
  mutate(across(Matches2:Matches3, as.numeric), Matches3 = replace_na(Matches3, 1))

I am not sure if Matches2 should be numeric. If you want Matches2 to remain character then you can simplify the expressions in mutate() with mutate(Matches3 = as.numeric(replace_na(Matches3, 1)))

Yes, this is much nicer than my solution.

A base R approach using sub/gsub and replace
data.frame(df,
           Matches1 = sub("(^.).*", "\\1", df$Matches),
           Matches2 = as.numeric(sub("^.(\\d+).*", "\\1", df$Matches)),
           Matches3 = as.numeric(gsub("^\\D\\d+|.*\\(|\\+)", "", df$Matches)) |>
             (\(x) replace(x, is.na(x), 1))())

output
  Testa Pre Fract Terms Time Matches Matches1 Matches2 Matches3
1    -1 NaN   NaN    -1  NaN     y15        y       15        1
2    -1 NaN   NaN    -1  NaN      b6        b        6        1
3    -1 NaN   NaN    -1  NaN      b7        b        7        1
4    -1 NaN   NaN    -1  NaN     b11        b       11        1
5    -1 NaN   NaN    -1  NaN      y9        y        9        1
6    -1 NaN   NaN    -1  NaN  b8(2+)        b        8        2
7    -1 NaN   NaN    -1  NaN y10(3+)        y       10        3
8    -1 NaN   NaN    -1  NaN b12(5+)        b       12        5


This is probably better done using regex, but here is a tidyverse way:
library(tidyr); library(dplyr)

df |>
  # take the first character for Matches1 
  separate_wider_position(
    Matches, c(Matches1 = 1, Matches2 = 1e9), too_few = 'align_start'
  # get everything before `(` for Matches2
  ) |> 
  separate_wider_delim(
    Matches2, '(', names = c('Matches2', 'Matches3'), too_few = 'align_start'
  ) |> 
  # get only the number from the last part, and replace missing with 1
  mutate(Matches3 = coalesce(parse_number(Matches3), 1))


# A tibble: 8 × 8
  Testa   Pre Fract Terms  Time Matches1 Matches2 Matches3
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <chr>    <chr>       <dbl>
1    -1   NaN   NaN    -1   NaN y        15              1
2    -1   NaN   NaN    -1   NaN b        6               1
3    -1   NaN   NaN    -1   NaN b        7               1
4    -1   NaN   NaN    -1   NaN b        11              1
5    -1   NaN   NaN    -1   NaN y        9               1
6    -1   NaN   NaN    -1   NaN b        8               2
7    -1   NaN   NaN    -1   NaN y        10              3
8    -1   NaN   NaN    -1   NaN b        12              5



Looking at @Andre Wildberg's approach, i.e. using same regex, you might try
within(X, {
  Matches3 = strtoi(gsub("^\\D\\d+|.*\\(|\\+)", "", Matches))
  Matches3[is.na(Matches3)] = 1L
  Matches2 = strtoi(sub("^.(\\d+).*", "\\1", Matches))
  Matches1 = substr(Matches, 1L, 1L)
  Matches = NULL # cosmetics
  })

gives
  Testa Pre Fract Terms Time Matches1 Matches2 Matches3
1    -1 NaN   NaN    -1  NaN        y       15        1
2    -1 NaN   NaN    -1  NaN        b        6        1
3    -1 NaN   NaN    -1  NaN        b        7        1
4    -1 NaN   NaN    -1  NaN        b       11        1
5    -1 NaN   NaN    -1  NaN        y        9        1
6    -1 NaN   NaN    -1  NaN        b        8        2
7    -1 NaN   NaN    -1  NaN        y       10        3
8    -1 NaN   NaN    -1  NaN        b       12        5

where X is the provided sample data.

An approach that splits substrings at opening parenthesis, if they're there, and adapts lengths.
> d |> 
+   transform(Matches=t(rbind(
+     substring(Matches, 1, 1),
+     sapply(
+         lapply(
+         strsplit(substring(Matches, 2), '\\(', perl=TRUE), 
+         gsub, pat="\\D", rep=""), 
+         `length<-`, 2)
+   ))) |> 
+   do.call(what='data.frame') |> 
+   within(Matches.3[is.na(Matches.3)] <- 1) |> 
+   type.convert(as.is=TRUE)
  Testa Pre Fract Terms Time Matches.1 Matches.2 Matches.3
1    -1 NaN   NaN    -1  NaN         y        15         1
2    -1 NaN   NaN    -1  NaN         b         6         1
3    -1 NaN   NaN    -1  NaN         b         7         1
4    -1 NaN   NaN    -1  NaN         b        11         1
5    -1 NaN   NaN    -1  NaN         y         9         1
6    -1 NaN   NaN    -1  NaN         b         8         2
7    -1 NaN   NaN    -1  NaN         y        10         3
8    -1 NaN   NaN    -1  NaN         b        12         5


If Matches pattern is really regular, another option with str_extract_all and unnest_wider is:
# PKGs (dplyr, tidyr) -----------------------------------------------------
library(tidyverse)

# Toy data ----------------------------------------------------------------
my_df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Testa, ~Pre, ~Fract, ~Terms, ~Time,  ~Matches,
  -1L,  NaN,    NaN,    -1L,   NaN,     "y15",
  -1L,  NaN,    NaN,    -1L,   NaN,      "b6",
  -1L,  NaN,    NaN,    -1L,   NaN,      "b7",
  -1L,  NaN,    NaN,    -1L,   NaN,     "b11",
  -1L,  NaN,    NaN,    -1L,   NaN,      "y9",
  -1L,  NaN,    NaN,    -1L,   NaN,  "b8(2+)",
  -1L,  NaN,    NaN,    -1L,   NaN, "y10(3+)",
  -1L,  NaN,    NaN,    -1L,   NaN, "b12(5+)")

# Code --------------------------------------------------------------------
my_df <- my_df %>% 
  mutate(Matches = str_extract_all(Matches, "^\\D|\\d+")) %>% 
  unnest_wider(Matches, names_sep = "_", transform = \(x) type.convert(replace_na(x, "1"), as.is = TRUE))

# Output ------------------------------------------------------------------
my_df
#> # A tibble: 8 × 8
#>   Testa   Pre Fract Terms  Time Matches_1 Matches_2 Matches_3
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <chr>         <int>     <int>
#> 1    -1   NaN   NaN    -1   NaN y                15         1
#> 2    -1   NaN   NaN    -1   NaN b                 6         1
#> 3    -1   NaN   NaN    -1   NaN b                 7         1
#> 4    -1   NaN   NaN    -1   NaN b                11         1
#> 5    -1   NaN   NaN    -1   NaN y                 9         1
#> 6    -1   NaN   NaN    -1   NaN b                 8         2
#> 7    -1   NaN   NaN    -1   NaN y                10         3
#> 8    -1   NaN   NaN    -1   NaN b                12         5

Created on 2024-07-25 with reprex v2.1.0
